# cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:

Tags: go

I use command `go get github.com/gorilla/mux`. I made http server using Golang, and I run this program :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
```

But I conflict this error :

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -i [/Users/imac/go/src]
http.go:9:5: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
Error: process exited with code 1.
```

My Go environment is here :

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/imac/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/v9/fkc_t97s5v1g9sr938zzvxvh0000gn/T/go-build096571864=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I fight with this error for a week, But I can't find out solution. Please help me.

Comment: try `go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux`

Comment: @YandryPozo It is same...

Comment: The error message says `($GOPATH not set)`.

Comment: My `$GOPATH` is `/User/imac/go`. Is it problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could you try this steps to debug it:

1. `ls -l /usr/local/go/src/github.com | grep gorilla`
2. `cd $GOPATH`

   `go list ... | grep gorilla`
3. if you din't see gorilla in the above two command, then you need to install it:
   `go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux`

Please run this: `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

How about running `go run main.go` ? is that working, if yes you should be able to do `go build` from your project path.

Comment: gorilla folder is not here. `/Users/imac/go/src/github.com` < in here...

Comment: You may need to install it. please do step 3. and let me know the output.

Comment: In 1 step, I see message `ls: /usr/local/go/src/github.com: No such file or directory`. In 2 step, I see path `github.com/gorilla/mux`. In 3 step, I install it but program is still show same error.

Comment: can u see by `go list ... | grep gorilla`

Comment: Yes. I can see path `github.com/gorilla/mux`.

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

Comment: i din't see $PATH in ur env var.

Comment: I have to store `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` in bash_profile?

Comment: just execute that command in cli and check if that works, if yes you can include into your .profile or .bash_profile

Comment: could you please paste the output of this cmd `echo $PATH $GOPATH`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/imac/go/bin:/Users/imac/go/bin /Users/imac/go`

Comment: Can u execute `go run main.go` from ur main script location ?

Comment: you can do `go build` or `go install` from the same path in terminal. Not sure about IDE part.

Comment: 1. cd to the path where your main script is `cd /path_to_main/script`                      2. `go build main.go` : this will create binaries into the same current directory.                                                                                                              3. If you want to install it `go install main.go`.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me...

1. **fire command**
   **> `go mod init <your-directoryNane-where-main.go-exist>`**
2. **fire command > `go get github.com/gorilla/mux`**

*after firing this both commands you will be able see 2 files :*

1. `go.mod`
2. `go.sum`

*finally, Close VS code and open again, the error will be resolved*

Comment: This was great solution!

Answer (score 6):

I wish this helpful.
You may off the 'mod'.

```sh
$ export GO111MODULE=off
```

Comment: Great, this works for me. The reason it wasn't working for me is that gorilla was being downloaded in the mod folder and not the src folder as expected.

Comment: After struggling for 2-3 hrs, this one worked for me.By default pkgs are installed in mod instead of src.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove quotes like this:

```
go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

Comment: Can you find `github.com/gorilla/mux` in $GOPATH/pkg subdirectory.
  
If not. Try `go install github.com/gorilla/mux`.

Comment: I try this but not working... `github.com/gorilla/mux` is in `$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **VS Code** as your IDE and facing this problem:

VS Code uses `$HOME/go` as your default `GOPATH` - if you export another `GOPATH` you running into this trouble.

**How to solve:**

1. Use the VS Code internal terminal and navigate to your project folder: `cd prjectFolder`. Type `go env` and check if the `GOPATH` entry is the same as you get when you use `cmd+t` and then `>Go: Current GOPATH`
2. If it doesn't fit, add in your user settings:

   `"go.gopath": "/some/path"`

   where `/some/path` is the same path you export in you shell, zsh and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I try to remove `github.com/gorilla` and `github.com/peterbourgon` directory, then, retry: `make`, it works.

[image]

```html
<pre>
fail log:


mac@user:~/TempPlace/temp/ngrok% make
go fmt ngrok/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/client/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/client/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/server/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/server/...
go get -tags 'debug' -d -v ngrok/...
src/ngrok/server/config.go:16:2: no Go files in /Users/apple/TempPlace/temp/ngrok/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
src/ngrok/server/config.go:17:2: no Go files in /Users/apple/TempPlace/temp/ngrok/src/github.com/peterbourgon/diskv
make: *** [deps] Error 1


success log:


mac@user:~/TempPlace/temp/ngrok% make
go fmt ngrok/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/client/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/client/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/server/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/server/...
go get -tags 'debug' -d -v ngrok/...
github.com/gorilla/websocket (download)
github.com/gorilla/mux (download)
src/ngrok/server/config.go:17:2: no Go files in /Users/apple/TempPlace/temp/ngrok/src/github.com/peterbourgon/diskv
make: *** [deps] Error 1
mac@user:~/TempPlace/temp/ngrok% make
go fmt ngrok/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/client/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/client/...
go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata
GOOS="" GOARCH="" go install github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
bin/go-bindata -nomemcopy -pkg=assets -tags=debug \
  -debug=true \
  -o=src/ngrok/server/assets/assets_debug.go \
  assets/server/...
go get -tags 'debug' -d -v ngrok/...
github.com/peterbourgon/diskv (download)
github.com/google/btree (download)
go install -tags 'debug' ngrok/main/ngrok
go install -ldflags "-s" -tags 'debug' ngrok/main/ngrokd

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `go build /Users/imac/go/src/project`

because  I see you try to use `go build` under `/Users/imac/go/src`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help other users running in Windows.
In my case I had to create two symlinks:

```
 1. run cmd as administrator  
 2. cd %gopath%  
 3. mklink /D src pkg\mod  
this creates a symlink between src and pkg\mod
 4. cd src\github.com\gorilla
```

Here you'll notice that the mux package might be listed as mux@v1.8.0

```
 5. mklink /D mux mux@v1.8.0
```

With this, go will be able to find github.com/gorilla/mux
under %gopath%\src\github.com\gorilla\mux

Finally, you have to set GO111Module to off
set GO111Module=off

and now you can build your app:

```
go build app.go
```