# cannot find package "github.com/gorrila/mux" in any of

Tags: go, mux

The error message is:

```
app.go:9:3: cannot find package "github.com/gorrila/mux" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/github.com/gorrila/mux (from 
$GOROOT)
    /Users/myname/go/src/github.com/gorrila/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

I understand GOROOT is for compiler tools that come with installation, so I am not sure why it looks for mux there. But I do see mux in the second location in my directory I created for go code.

I know this question was asked [once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539909/cannot-find-package-github-com-gorilla-mux-in-any-of/41540554) and I tried to debug following the advice from that question.

I used homebrew and installed go version `go1.10.3 darwin/amd64`.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant portion of my go env:

```
GOPATH="/Users/myname/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
```

I also set my bash profile, excluding GOROOT because [that is no longer required](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really):

```
export GOPATH="/Users/myname/go/src/github.com"
export PATH="/Users/myname/go/src/github.com/bin:$PATH"
```

And did `source ~/.bash_profile`.

This setup was enough that I can run basic go programs like hello world. So I then tried to run code using the `mux` library.

I first installed mux within the directory of my program (cd'd into `/Users/myname/go/src/github.com/myname/restapi`).

Then I ran:

```
go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
```

I can see the folder exists in my finder. I also looked in terminal:

```
ls -l /Users/myname/go/src/github.com | grep gorilla
=> drwxr-xr-x  3 myname  staff  102 Jun 29 14:35 gorilla
```

Then:

```
cd $GOPATH (/Users/myname/go)
go list ... | grep gorilla 
=> can't load package: package ../..: no Go files in /Users
```

So I saw gorilla in the first command but not the second. However, I do see the gorilla directory further within my go directory, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Running `go build` returns the package of concern:

```
app.go:9:3: cannot find package "github.com/gorrila/mux" in any of:
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/github.com/gorrila/mux 
(from $GOROOT)
  /Users/myname/go/src/github.com/gorrila/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

I am not sure why it is looking for mux within the usr directory. Is there an issue with any of my paths? I keep checking that last path to see that the mux directory is there.

Comment: Packages are looked up in GOROOT first, because that's where the stdlib lives. `go list` doesn't work at the root of `GOPATH` because the go tool works on packages. Does the directory `/Users/myname/go/src/github.com/gorrila/mux` actually exist, and does it contain `.go` files?

Comment: @JimB Looking in my directory in the terminal I see that `/Users/myname/go/src/github.com/gorrila/mux` does exist and it contains files like mux.go, mux_test.go, route.go, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled `"github.com/gorilla/mux"` – it has one "r" and two "l"'s.  (Carefully compare the `go get` command you quoted and the `import` statement in your source file.)

Comment: Got it, I did misspell the toolkit in my file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set your `.bash_profile` in this way:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Comment: Hi, I set that exactly within my `.bash_profile` and am receiving the identical error as listed above.